# How to use permission_required decorator in django views

Tags: django, authentication

How to use django permission_required in tempatlate language. 
I want to show some `LINK` if the user have certain permission.

```
@permission_required('tracking.view_visitor')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something like you're asking. Adapting what I've done to your case, you'd have in the view:

```
template = loader.get_template('foo/foo.html')
context = RequestContext(
    request,
    {
        'can_view': request.user.has_perm('tracking.view_visitor')),
    })
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

In the template:

```
{% if can_view %}
    <!-- whatever you need -->
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do something like :

```
extra_context = {}
if request.user.has_perm('tracking.view_visitor'):
    extra_context['show_links']     = True
else:
    pass
```

And in your template , you can check it with :

```
{% if show_links %}
    display htmls or links
{% endif %}
```

Make sure to pass context while rendering . :)